# Restart gunicorn in django codes

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I deployed my Django application to the internet and every time after changing codes, I have to run this command to make changes happen:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Is there any way to run this command through codes (for example in views)? or schedule it?
Or is there any way to force Gunicorn restarts after changing in codes?

I have tried [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fabric script to restart gunicorn.
Check this link [Automate Deployment With Fabric Python](https://medium.com/gopyjs/automate-deployment-with-fabric-python-fad992e68b5)

Comment: Thank you Mehran, every time to run this, I have to run this command:`fab development deploy`. Am I right?

Comment: yes, as long you can connect to your remote server correctly through fabric :)